# Using criteriabuilder to build type safe select with treat

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a base abstract class for a table, the abstract class does not keep all the columns

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MYTABLE")
public abstract class MyTable {
    //...
}
```

Normally I get the required column data from its derived classes using `treat` in criteriabuilder

```
@Entity
public class MyClassA extends MyTable {
    //...
}
@Entity
public class MyClassB extends MyTable {
    //...
}

Root<MyTable> myTable = cq.from(MyTable.class);
cq.where(cb.or(
    cb.equal(cb.treat(myTable, MyClassA.class).get(MyClassA_.infoA), "A"),
    cb.equal(cb.treat(myTable, MyClassB.class).get(MyClassB_.infoB), "B")
))
```

Here both infoA and infoB are the same column in MYTABLE in the database.

My question is how do you write a type-safe select to select both infoA and infoB in a single select?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if there is a real reason not to move both the infoA and infoB variables into your base class, as OO principles suggest, since it simplifies everything then.

But if you made it unintentionally, I would suggest making that small refactorings and use inheritance mapping with all the benefits provided by ORM frameworks:

```
@Entity
public abstract class MyTable {

    @javax.persistence.Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long Id;

    private String info;

    public String getInfo() {
        return info;
    }

    public void setInfo(String info) {
        this.info = info;
    }

    public Long getId() {
       return Id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
       Id = id;
    }
}

@Entity
public class MyClassA extends MyTable {
    //...
}
@Entity
public class MyClassB extends MyTable {
    //...
}
```

So that you will be able to query your MyClassA and MyClassB entites polymorphicly:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<MyTable> query = builder.createQuery( MyTable.class );
        Root<MyTable> root = query.from( MyTable.class );
        query.select( root );
        List<MyTable> entities = entityManager.createQuery( query ).getResultList();
```

In case of Hibernate, just check out the following:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance

Comment: Thanks. I don't know the reason too, thats not my code. But let say I have to work with this code, how do I select both infoA and infoB as a single column in the result?